# bypass FreeMarker caching?

Tags: java, caching, freemarker

Is it possible to bypass the Freemarker cache when certain templates are requested? I realise that I'll probably have to implement my own TemplateLoader in order to do this, but even so, I can't see a way to check the cache when say template A is requested, but bypass it when template B is requested?

If this is not possible, I'll just have to disable caching completely.

Comment: Are you using freemarker directly or through some web framework ?

Answer (score 3):

try disabling caching on your [configuration](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#setTemplateUpdateDelay(int)):

```
configuration.setTemplateUpdateDelay(0);
```

This should cause it to check for a newer version of a template every time it's requested.

To skip the cache for only certain templates, you only need to override `getLastModified` to return a very old date for certain templates, forcing a reload.

Answer (score 1):

You would set this on the configuration object itself. See [this page](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html#pgui_config_templateloading_caching) for details.

For your particular problem, you could do the following:

```
cfg.setSetting(Configuration.CACHE_STORAGE_KEY, "strong:0, soft:0");
```